# Merge part of a pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

New Git and Github user.  Is it possible to accept/merge only part of a Pull Request?

For example if there is a Pull Request on Github that has 4 commits but you only want to use 2 of them, is there a way to simply merge the 2 and disregard the other 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the pull request is all or nothing.

You can recreate the pull request by making a branch up to only the commits you need and merge that.

You can do this via

```
git cherry-pick
```

Or

```
git rebase -i
```